# $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix rank given $m < n$ then find answer of following.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, hermitian-matrices

This question was asked in my masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it.

> Let M be a $n\times n$  Hermitian matrix of rank $k (k<n)$ . If $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with corresponding unit column vector u  then which of the following are true.

A. Rank$(M-\lambda u u*)$=k-1.

B. Rank$(M-\lambda u u*)$=k.

C. Rank$(M-\lambda u u*)$=k+1.

D.  Rank${(M-\lambda u u*)}^n= M^n- {\lambda}^n uu*$.

I am sorry I would not be able to give anything as attempt as I am not really good at  problem solving in linear algebra. Also, I could not decide which result I should use. I am blank on this question.

Looking for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that D makes any sense ? Try to prove result A.

Comment: Hint: $M$ can be written as $M = \sum_{i=1}^k{\lambda_i u_i u_i^*}$